# Switching from Wayland to X11 breaks my dual-monitor setup

Tags: debian, gnome, multi-monitor

I've recently installed Debian 12/GNOME. I have a dual-monitor setup. My primary screen is landscape; my secondary screen is portrait. When I initially installed Debian and setup my monitors, all was great and wonderful. Then I realized that, by default, Debian was using Wayland. (I have some apps that are X11 only.) So I log out, use the gear icon to choose GNOME under X11, and log in. BAM! My screen layout is broken. My 2nd monitor (portrait) looks fine. My main monitor is split; the left side is half of monitor 1 and the right side is half of monitor 2. If I open an app - say Settings - I have to "phantom drag" (i.e. put the mouse where I think the app window is) it to the portrait monitor before I can use it. Nothing I do will bring the displays together.

I should be clear: it's more than a broken layout; mousing is even different. I cannot use my mouse on anything in the landscape monitor.

**I am not well versed when it comes to desktops in Linux.** I've web search this issue to death and everything I find is old(er) and nothing quite fits my issue. The closest I can find is [this](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=153962) - specifically image 3 where you can see that "monitors 1 and 2" are split/offset on the main screen.

Hardware: NVIDIA GTX 1650, two LG 27" monitors

I don't even know where to start to fix this issue.